# Access properties of class without creating an instance of the class

Tags: c#, blazor

I wanna to access the properties of a class without using an instance of the class. My service:

```
public async Task<MovieDataDetail> GetAllMovieInfo(string title, string lang = "ru")
        {
            var results = await _client.SearchMovieAsync(title, lang);
            var data = results.Results.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title == title);

            return new MovieDataDetail
            {
                Id = data.Id,
                Title = data.Title,
                OriginalTitle = data.OriginalTitle,
                Overview = data.Overview,
                ReleaseDate = data.ReleaseDate
            };
        }
```

It writes data to the [properties](https://github.com/INTERNALINTERFERENCE/testproj/blob/main/GetInformationAboutMovie/MovieDataDetail.cs)

I would like to use these props on a client but I don't know how to do it without creating the instance of a class.
I'd like to do something like that: `<div><h1>@MovieDataDetail.Overview</h1></div>`

If I create the instance of `MovieDataDetail`, `Overview` will be null

Comment: Given that the overview appears to come from a database, how do you intend to fetch/display it without querying the database?

Comment: @canton7 no, I don't use any database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple object management problem.

Instead of creating a (new) instance just assign the result to a variable in your page:

```
private MovieDataDetail movieDetail = null;

...
   movieDetail = await GetAllMovieInfo(...);
```

and in the markup section:

```
@if(movieDetail != null)
{
   <div><h1>@movieDetail.Overview</h1></div>
}
```

Comment: I have another error - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you notice the `@if()` ?  I added that a little later.

Comment: oh, it works now. Strange things.. thanks a lot